# Create entity with key Google Datastore NDB Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to create an entity, but it seems like each time I save/persist an entity for the first time, it would save it with an id rather than with a key name. Here is my code:

```
if company.count() < 1:
  # save the company
  company = Companies(key_name=account)
  company.account = account
  company.status = status
  company.put()
```

I also tried this on ndb:

```
if company.count() < 1:
  # save the company
  company = Companies()
  company.key_name = account
  company.account = account
  company.status = status
  company.put()
```

Another observation is saving the datastore would only create a key name if `get_or_insert` function was used, but this seems to edit the existing data if this is the code.

```
company = Companies.get_or_insert(account)
company.account = account
company.status = status
company.put()
```

**Two questions:**

1. If this was a new main account, would it be advisable to use `get_or_insert` function? Is this recommended just as long as you have a good if statement ?
2. If the answer is no to the first question, how can we save without using `get_or_insert` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NDB you must use id instead of key_name.

Comment: Should ID also be used in child entities instead of a key_name?

Comment: Yes, when using NDB there is no such thing as key_name, it's always id.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In connection to the question, when is the right way to use get_or_insert function given that the key_name is generated by get_or_insert? Should we even use get_or_insert at all?

Comment: No, get_or_insert() uses the first argument as the id (key_name). And you can pass ketword args to set property values if it creates the entity only.